# Selecting multiple CSS ids with only 1 number changing on each

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an issue I am trying to select multiple CSS classes / ids.

The way my theme calls multiple buttons is it adds +1 to the button id like so:

```
edit-add-to-wishlist
edit-add-to-wishlist--1
edit-add-to-wishlist--2
edit-add-to-wishlist--3
etc
```

I wish to make said buttons all float to the right, without having to individually name and create each id in the CSS.

I have attempted to use the `nth:child` option as well as the `*` universal selector without much success.

Is selecting multiple a range (I guess you would call it) possible?

Something like this:

```
#edit-add-to-wishlist--* {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd add a `class` along with your `id` to differentiate between 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. That way you don't have multiple `id`s that are similar except for one digit and you can accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: show me your block of code not just the ids

Comment: @SergioWizenfeld Why would he need to do that?

Comment: for example if you have them in a <ul class="wish"> <li id="edit-add-to-wishlist"></li>
<li id="edit-add-to-wishlist" > </li>
<li id="edit-add-to-wishlist" > </li>
</ul>

you can call all of them by doing ul.wish li{ color:red };

Comment: @SergioWizenfeld He made it fairly clear that's not what he was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector: `[attr*=value]`:

```
[id*=edit-add-to-wishlist] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9evGy/) - it works

It selects all instances where a `id` contains `edit-add-to-wishlist`

> [attr*=value]
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

[MDN documentation on the attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: I thought the OP said it added 1 to the ID?

Comment: @DevlshOne Yep - they did.

Comment: K.. just keeping ya honest, bud.

Answer (score 0):

```
button[id^=edit-add-to-wishlist] {float:right}
```

Uses CSS3's substring matching by looking for `<button id="edit-add-to-wishlist*>` where the asterisk is a wildcard.